# MDT 2013u1 Company Selection

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, mdt, mdt-2013

I work for an MSP, and we support 7 companies, each with their own application requirements, and each company can have either Windows 7, 8, or 10 installed based on what they request. I wanted to do company based installs in MDT, ie selecting company, OS, and limiting available applications to install based on company selection, without increasing management overhead too much.

I had a few ideas of what to do but not really sure how to proceed. My first idea was to create a task sequence and selection profile for each company, then add a page in the wizard for OS selection.

I saw in the UDI Wizard Designer that there is a page called VolumePage to do basically what I was looking for. I haven't used the UDI Wizard Designer before so I'm not overly familiar with it, but from what I can tell at least the VolumePage uses integration with SCCM. All references I've found to configuring the VolumePage have been using MDT along side SCCM, and the server I manage only has MDT 2013u1 not SCCM. Procuring SCCM is not an available option for the time being.

I had also considered setting up a selection profile for each company, and a task sequence for each OS. I would have to add in a page for Selection Profile in the wizard to do this, or configure something in the database, both of which I'm not very familiar with. I have SQL Server Express 2008 installed and set up a database for MDT, but I haven't configured any settings in the database since I have limited DB experience.

I know the most simple method would be to create task sequences for each company and each OS, but I don't want to have 28 task sequences, and it seems like there has to be a way to do this without having so many task sequences.

Is there any way to set this up using only MDT and the DB?

Comment: Here is something, make a boot image for each company. The image for the company will contain the auto selected task sequence for that company (I am coming from a zero touch setup using only MDT and WDS and no DB or SCCM). Do you think that will do the trick?

Comment: Do I have to set up a separate Deployment Share to create different boot images? And how would I auto select a Task Sequence or Selection Profile from the boot image?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I am writing the instructions right now.

Answer (score 0):

Are you well versed in MDT? If so then read the `TL;DR` section at the bottom.

---

To make a boot image automatically select a TaskSequence, you need to know your task sequence ID.

You can get that from the task sequence list:

[image: Location of Task Sequence ID]

After you know your Task Sequence ID you will need to create (or modify) the `TaskSequenceID` property in the `bootstrap.ini` file of your deployment share to reflect the TS ID that you want to automatically select.

Right click on your deployment share and push properties.

[image: Open the Deployment Share Properties]

Now create (or change) the `TaskSequenceID` property to equal your TS ID. You can place it in the `[Default]` section or the `Architecture ([x86], [x64], [IA-64], etc...)` section, if you use it.

Example of configuration text: `TaskSequenceID=EXAMPLE1`.

[image: Configure the property]

Now push the OK button to save your settings and close the properties window.

[image: Save your work]

Next, Right click the deployment share and click the "`Update Deployment Share`" option.

[image: Open the update deployment share dialog]

Now completely regenerate the boot images. I use this option as it deletes the previous images and rebuilds from scratch, giving you the smallest and freshest images possible. Although in theory you *should* be able to use any of the other options.

[image: Regenerate the boot images]

Click next to the confirmation and it will start rebuilding the boot images.

[image: Image rebuild in progress...]

Now navigate to your Deployment share folder and open the `Boot` directory.
You can find your deployment share path by looking at the deployment share name in the workbench.

In the `Boot` folder, copy the `LiteTouchPE_x86.wim` file and the `LiteTouchPE_x64.wim` file to some other directory E.G. `C:\Temp\LTI_ZTI\WIMs\`

[image: Copy the boot images to a different location]

---

Now do the same above process with TS IDs. Eventually you will have a boot image for each task sequence. You will be able to boot to the image of your selection and it will automatically run the provided task sequence.

---

**Links:**

MDT 2010 ZTI: https://scriptimus.wordpress.com/2011/06/07/mdt-2010-fully-automated-lite-touch-deployment/

MDT 2012 ZTI: https://scriptimus.wordpress.com/2013/02/18/lti-deployments-skipping-deployment-wizard-panes/

ZTIflow.wsf and Customsettings.ini advanced stuff: http://myitforum.com/myitforumwp/2013/03/14/a-look-at-ztigather-and-the-customsettings-ini-file/

Custom Wizard Pages: https://itmicah.wordpress.com/2014/01/25/create-a-custom-deployment-wizard-pane-for-updates-mdt/

---

**TL;DR**

Make a boot image with the `TaskSequenceID` property of `bootstrap.ini` pointing to the TS ID that you want to use. Do this for each TS that you want to have automatically selected.